# How to Check Current User Exists in AD Group using Rest Api

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, active-directory, domain

We have a SharePoint 2013 On premise environments and having the Domain Groups with the Names contains SPECIAL characters as **(Role)x$Customer$2838**.

Using the below  rest call i am able to get all the  Groups.

```
"/_api/web/siteusers?$select=id,Title&$filter=PrincipalType eq 4";
```

Now i want to Check the Current login user exists in a specific Domain Group using Rest api.

Comment: Are you getting all the users from that group using the URL you mentioned in question?

Comment: @TARUN Have you added the Domain group into SharePoint group?

Comment: @SohailShaikh No it was not added into the SharePoint Group

Comment: @TARUN Are you able to get all users from that group using the REST Url mentioned?

Comment: @SohailShaikh with the above URL I am able to get all the AD groups List available in the site

Comment: @TARUN Is it possible/okay for you to add AD group into SharePoint group?

Comment: @SohailShaikh Its Possible

Comment: For me, even when there is no object within the group it is returning true. Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

First add the AD group into a SharePoint group.
You can set the group setting "Who can view the membership of the group" in SP-Group-Settings to "Group Members". Then only members of the group can see the members of that group. Luckily you can ask if the current-user has the right to view a groups membership. So if the user can view the membership of the group then he/she must be a member

Use below REST Url:

`http://<siteurl>/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('SharePointGroupName')/CanCurrentUserViewMembership`

The above REST will return a boolean value depending on whether user is part of the AD group or not.

Comment: that's a very smart workaround, @Sohail!